# Dump from AWS to Local using DataGrip or WorkBench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, workbench, datagrip

I am a read-only user in the db and whenever I try to dump, I get the following error

I am on Ubuntu: 18.0.4
Mysql 5.7
Server MySQl: 5.7

````
[2020-05-06 20:46:31] /usr/bin/mysqldump db_name --complete-insert --skip-lock-tables --result-file=/home/user/Desktop/dumps --user=user --host=<host.name.com> --port=3306
mysqldump: Can't create/write to file '/home/user/Desktop/dumps' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
[2020-05-06 20:46:31] mysqldump process finished```
````

Comment: Is dumps a directory? You need to specify an output file name, not a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a file not a directory.

According to error message `Can't create/write to file '/home/user/Desktop/dumps' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)`